# Can there be a formula $\psi$ such that $(\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi))$ is a theorem of L?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can there be a formula $\psi$ such that $(\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi))$ is a theorem of L?

I would like to check my answer. I thought:

No it cannot be a theorem of L. Because to be a theorem of L it must be a tautology but if we constructed the truth table we would see that it's not a tautology.

Comment: is that any better?

Comment: Are you sure you mean formula and not sentence? I think the answer is yes anyway, just recall that $\psi\to\neg\psi$ is equivalent to $\neg\psi\vee\neg\psi$ which in turn is equivalent to $\neg\psi$.

Comment: @ZZS14 Yes, much better. Thanks!

Comment: the question in my past paper definitely says formula

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be theorem, let $\psi=(p\land (\neg p))$. The truth table for this will verify that $(\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi))$ is true and completeness will ensure it is a theorem.

The problem with your argument is that you want to attribute truth values to the formula $\psi$, but you should be attributing them to the propositional letters that occur in $(\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi))$. This is how [valuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_formula#Truth-value_assignments.2C_formula_evaluations) are defined.

Comment: oh i see that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @ZZS14 You're welcome.

Comment: @ZZS14 - the "trick", as showed by GitGud's answer, is that the problem ask you : "Can there be a formula ψ such that ... ?" and the answer is YES. Of course, you are right in saying that $(ψ→(¬ψ))$ is **not** a tautology, and this implies that not **all** formulae that you can obtain from it with a subst are "good". Is the other way round: if $\varphi$ is *taut*, then **all** subst instances are "good".

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation on Git Gud's theme: we have ⊥ ⊢ φ, and in particular ⊥ ⊢ $\neg \psi$, so if $\psi$ is false that would do it.